# Modifying the default window title in Android for a tablet?

Tags: android, window, contextmenu, title, custom-titlebar

I am looking for a way to slightly modify the default window title in an Android app for both phone and tablet. The example below is a tablet view of the title bar as standard:

[image: android window title bar]

I have tried implementing a custom title bar, which works but the context menu (circled in red) disappears, which I need. All I want to do is change the color of the bottom border or remove the bottom border altogether.

Is there a way to make changes whilst keeping the context menu?

Thanks

Comment: are you using action bar sherlock library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest in application tag define as :

```
android:theme="@style/mytheme"
```

Now in res/values you can define a file say theme.xml with content as :

```
<resources> 
<style name="mytheme" parent="@android:style/Theme" > 
   <item name="android:_DEFAULT_BASE_COLOR_1">#XXXXXX</item>
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    ... . 
</style>
</resources>
```

This will change the basic colour scheme of your application. Here are the color themes primarily used on Android: http://developer.android.com/design/style/color.html